# What is a cyclic group with exactly one generator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm thinking something made up of only g in G and the identity... Not sure though.

Comment: Yes, that will to it. The one you are thinking of can be described as the group whose elements are $0$ and $1$, and where the operation is addition modulo $2$.

Comment: What would be the generator for this?

Comment: @user104203: There are only two options. Have you checked either of them?

Comment: The generator is $1$.  The only other candidate doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The generator $g$ equal its inverse $g^{-1}$, $gg^{-1} = g^2 = 1$, $G$ is the trivial group or $Z/2$.

Comment: A trivial group only has subgroups of the identity and itself, right?

Comment: A trivial group contains only one element: the identity. If you want explicit examples of groups satisfying the two possibilities, consider $C_1=\{0\}$ and $C_2=\{1,-1\},$ with multiplication as the operation in both cases. You should be able to prove that both of them are cyclic groups. In fact, these are the unique cyclic groups of order $1$ and $2$ (up to isomorphism).

Comment: Apologies for the typo. I intended to say $C_1=\{1\},$ though what I said actually works fine.